# How to get last option value between multiple selects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a problem to getting last selected option value in multiple select boxes the problem is, I have 4 select boxes you can see in the below image. I want to get the last option value through jquery.

I have tried this code but not getting the last exact value.

```
$('.option').find('option:selected').attr("name")
```

[image]

This is my form.

```
<form method="post" id="form-id">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Size</label>
    <select class="form-control option" name="size" required>
        <option value="">Choose option</option>
        <option>8.2 * 11.6 in (A4)</option>
        <option>11.7 x 16.5 in (A3)</option>
        <option>16.5 x 23.4 in (A2)</option>
        <option>23.4 x 33.1 in (A1)</option>
        <option>33.1 x 46.8 in (A0)</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Paper</label>
    <select class="form-control option" name="paper" required>
        <option value="">Choose option</option>
        <option>A4</option>
        <option>A3</option>
        <option>A2</option>
        <option>A1</option>
        <option>A0</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Appearance</label>
    <select class="form-control option" name="appearance" required>
        <option value="">Choose option</option>
        <option>Black & White</option>
        <option>Color</option>
        <option>Color Division</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Large Format Binding</label>
    <select class="form-control option" name="binding" required>
        <option value="">Choose Option</option>
        <option>No Binding</option>
        <option>Blk Edge w/ Craft Paper (<span class="amount">&#36;3.50</span>)</option>
        <option>Blk Edge w/o Craft Paper (<span class="amount">&#36;2.00</span>)</option>
        <option>Full Bind and Label (<span class="amount">&#36;4.00</span>)</option>
        <option>Post Bind &#8211; Drilled Holes w/ Screw Post (<span class="amount">&#36;5.00</span>)</option>
        <option>Post Bind w/ Black Edge (<span class="amount">&#36;6.00</span>)</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success cart" style="display:none"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
```

And this is my script

```
<script>
$('.option').change(function () {

    var check = $(this).val();

    var name = $(this).attr("name");

    if($('[name=paper]').val() == '' || $('[name=size]').val() == '' || $('[name=appearance]').val() == '' || $('[name=binding]').val() == '')
    {
        if(name == 'size')
        {
            if(check == '')
            {
                $('#size').html('<font color=red> Please select a size </font>');
                $('.cart').hide();
            }
            $('#size').html(check);
        }
        else if(name == 'paper')
        {
            if(check == '')
            {
                $('#paper').html('<font color=red> Please select a paper </font>');
                $('.cart').hide();
            }
            $('#paper').html(check);
        }
        else if(name == 'appearance')
        {
            if(check == '')
            {
                $('#appearance').html('<font color=red> Please select appearance </font>');
                $('.cart').hide();
            }
            $('#appearance').html(check);
        }
        else if(name == 'binding')
        {
            if(check == '')
            {
                $('#binding').html('<font color=red> Please select a binding </font>');
                $('.cart').hide();
            }
            $('#binding').html(check);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log($('.option').val());
        $('.cart').show();
        return false;
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: what you are not understanding in this problem @DavidThomas

Comment: Unclear what you are asking - you have 4 select boxes. You wish to get... the selected option from the 4th `<select>`? WHEN do you want to get that - when *it* is selected? Or when *any* of the four select control's values are changed? Or... ?

Comment: `$('option').find('option:selected')` will never return results.  An '<option>' cannot be a child of another options, which is what `find()` looks for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the last option value through jquery.

So that is the last user selection, not the last `<select>` having a selection made...
   *(Answer edited based on comments)*.
So I assume you simply want `$(this).val()` to be console logged.

I modified the submit button show/hide... But I didn't get where you wished to display some additionnal hints... So I skipped that.

I think that is a good starter... Have fun coding!

```js
$('.option').on('change',function () {

  $('.option').each(function(){ // To show the submit button ONLY if all 4 dropdowns hold not empty value.
    $('.cart').show();
    if($(this).val() == ""){
      $('.cart').hide();
    }
  });
  
  var this_change = $(this).val();
  if(this_change == ""){
    this_change = 'User selected the default "Choose option"';
  }
  console.log(this_change);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" id="form-id">
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Size</label>
  <select class="form-control option" name="size" required>
    <option value="">Choose option</option>
    <option>8.2 * 11.6 in (A4)</option>
    <option>11.7 x 16.5 in (A3)</option>
    <option>16.5 x 23.4 in (A2)</option>
    <option>23.4 x 33.1 in (A1)</option>
    <option>33.1 x 46.8 in (A0)</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Paper</label>
  <select class="form-control option" name="paper" required>
    <option value="">Choose option</option>
    <option>A4</option>
    <option>A3</option>
    <option>A2</option>
    <option>A1</option>
    <option>A0</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Appearance</label>
  <select class="form-control option" name="appearance" required>
    <option value="">Choose option</option>
    <option>Black & White</option>
    <option>Color</option>
    <option>Color Division</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Large Format Binding</label>
  <select class="form-control option" name="binding" required>
    <option value="">Choose Option</option>
    <option>No Binding</option>
    <option>Blk Edge w/ Craft Paper (<span class="amount">&#36;3.50</span>)</option>
    <option>Blk Edge w/o Craft Paper (<span class="amount">&#36;2.00</span>)</option>
    <option>Full Bind and Label (<span class="amount">&#36;4.00</span>)</option>
    <option>Post Bind &#8211; Drilled Holes w/ Screw Post (<span class="amount">&#36;5.00</span>)</option>
    <option>Post Bind w/ Black Edge (<span class="amount">&#36;6.00</span>)</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success cart" style="display:none"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
```

Comment: if I select all values in the select boxes it returns the last value but if I change the value next time it did not return that select value. all the time it returns the old value.

Comment: Do you wish the last changed by the user, regardless of the `<select>` order in the form? If so, that is different... And way more simple.

Comment: yes, every time I need last selected value in the select boxes

Comment: I edited my answer... Please be more specific next time, you would have had an answer real more quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the value of select tag, use `.val()` to get the current value selected

Instead of this

```
$('.option').find('option:selected').attr("name")
```

Change it to this

```
$('.option').val()
```

Comment: I get nothing when every time i change the value.

Comment: have you tried adding values in options? how about edit your post and add your codes, so I can see the problem more clear

Comment: still getting the same problem

Comment: I have added my code please help me i am stuck with this problem

Comment: `$('.option').val()` have you tried this? its getting the value of the option. use `console.log()` or `alert()` so you can properly debug your code.